# High resolution on small screen

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I just purchased a new ultrabook (Asus UX32VD).   Awesome laptop, but I am having trouble using it with its native resolution being 1920 x 1080.  Text is so small and hard to read. I have increased the text size in the display options but it don't really improve it for all scenarios, especially in webpages.

I am wondering if there is a possible solution to this?  Simply lowering the resolution makes everything look pixelated.

Comment: Have you tried a "custom text size", which can increase the DPI used by the Windows fonts to more than the 100/125/150% choices?

Comment: Yep I have but it doesn't work for everything.  It seems that the apps need to support this feature to work properly.

Comment: Beware that after setting a "custom text size", some apps will use that large font size in a dumb manner, e.g. a dialog pop-up window might have a fixed size (adequate for "normal sized" text) so the  big text and select buttons are cropped out!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the default text size for your browser to cope with the webpages aspect of your problem.

In Chrome (for example) go to `chrome://chrome/settings/` and click on the "Advanced Settings" link.

This will give you more options including one section called "Web Content". There is an option called "Page Zoom". Change that to a value greater than 100% to increase the size of all web pages. The Zoom option on the options menu only does the current page.

In Firefox go to **Tools > Options > Content** and increase the Size of the default font.

Comment: you can set minimum font size in Firefox, some websites thing it is cool to set text to grey50% and fontsize to  80% making it hard to read. Some even set fontsize to a fixed number, this ignores the default, but the browser will not go below minimum.

Comment: Why do you assume that he is talking about a browser?

Comment: @soandos - because the OP states "especially in webpages" in the question.

Comment: I know of the increase font size in webpages, but it's still not my solution.  That will only work for browsers, which is what I have to be doing.  I not a fan of doing that either, because I do a lot of web development and that settings changes what a webpage is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

The primary controls available include

1. Personalize the display properties text size to 150%
2. Review other [accessibility controls](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Make-the-computer-easier-to-see-optimize-visual-display)
3. In web-browsers use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to increase the text size temporarily.
4. In other applications, increase the font-size in each apps settings.
5. Connect a physically larger display where convenient.